# How to adjust Plotly legend/colorbar background transparency/colour

Tags: python, plotly-python, colorbar

I'm trying to edit the appearance of a map I have made, but if I choose to have the colorbar/legend visible, it sits on a white background:

[image]

This white is a bit jarring for the rest of the color scheme. At the moment, I'm just hiding the whole thing with:

```
fig.update_coloraxes(showscale=False)
```

But that obviously makes the map harder to understand, so is there a way I can still show the bar either with a darker background or without a background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute [`bgcolor`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/coloraxis/#layout-coloraxis-colorbar-bgcolor) of `colorbar`:

```
color = ... # your color
fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar=dict(bgcolor=color))
```